# How do i call a function after a button has been clicked on DOM

Tags: javascript, function, dom, button, onclick

I have a test button setup that works when it is clicked on, it is able to display an alert or confirm window. However i want it to display a list of items, i have the code for the list but i cant seem to bring it up when the button is clicked. I am using all DOM, so no jquery required. thank you

```
var creatbtndiv = document.createElement("div");
var creatbtn = document.createElement("button");
creatbtn.innerHTML = "Click Me";

creatbtndiv.appendChild(creatbtn);

document.body.appendChild(creatbtndiv);



var list = function (name) {
    var creatDiv = document.createElement("div");
    creatDiv.id = "submenudiv";
    creatDiv.className = "submenudiv";

    var creatul = document.createElement("ul");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    li = doument.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "Submenu" + index;
    creatul.appendChild(li);
    }

    creatDiv.appendChild(creatul);

    document.body.appendChild(name);


};



creatbtndiv.onclick = function () {
    var alert = confirm("yes master");
    list();
};
```

Comment: Does your console give you an error message? (nice for going vanilla btw)

Comment: This works in http://jsfiddle.net - Eh, sorry, I just saw the popup, not the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "Submenu" + i; <----------- Replace index with "i"
creatul.appendChild(li);
}

creatDiv.appendChild(creatul);

document.body.appendChild(creatDiv); <----------- Replace "name" with "createDiv"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few syntax errors on your code. Like `doument`, and using the variable `index`, when it should be `i`. And in the end of the List method, on `document.body.appendChild` you should pass the `creatDiv` as argument.

Looks like some CopyPaste mistakes ahn...

http://jsfiddle.net/ayvNZ/

Here is the working code:

```
var creatbtndiv = document.createElement("div");
var creatbtn = document.createElement("button");
creatbtn.innerHTML = "Click Me";

creatbtndiv.appendChild(creatbtn);

document.body.appendChild(creatbtndiv);



var list = function () {
    var creatDiv = document.createElement("div");
    creatDiv.id = "submenudiv";
    creatDiv.className = "submenudiv";

    var creatul = document.createElement("ul");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Submenu" + i;
        creatul.appendChild(li);
    }

    creatDiv.appendChild(creatul);
    document.body.appendChild(creatDiv);
};



creatbtndiv.onclick = function () {
    var alert = confirm("yes master");
    list();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a correct fiddle, your code has a few errors in it. http://jsfiddle.net/8LZKc/

```
li = doument.createElement("li"); <-- should be document
```

`index` is not defined, you wanted `i`

`name` is not an element, you wanted `creatDiv` there insead

Answer (score 0):

document was spelled wrong in the list item loop.  Index isn't used anywhere, switched to use the indexer of 'i'.  Name parameter isn't used or provided a value but creatDiv is the target element your creating for your list.

```
var creatbtndiv = document.createElement("div");
var creatbtn = document.createElement("button");
creatbtn.innerHTML = "Click Me";

creatbtndiv.appendChild(creatbtn);

document.body.appendChild(creatbtndiv);

var list = function (name) {
    var creatDiv = document.createElement("div");
    creatDiv.id = "submenudiv";
    creatDiv.className = "submenudiv";

    var creatul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Submenu" + i;
        creatul.appendChild(li);
    }

    creatDiv.appendChild(creatul);

    document.body.appendChild(creatDiv);
};



creatbtndiv.onclick = function () {
    var alert = confirm('yes master');
    list();
};
```